# WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 Docker Compose MySQL too many conections

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I started to test locally the version 3.2.0 of WSO2 API Manager, and I started with docker-compose distribution. Run it with docker-compose is very straight forward and for testing it is the best option. Every component started fine, and I got into devportal without any problem. I could list the Default application created by default. But I tried to access to publisher and It was not possible. I checked logs and my surprise was a MySql error, too may connections. Even I did not used the gateway to hit any API.

`Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Too many connections`

I did not touch any config file. How is it possible to get this error in a fresh release? It is a easy config change to fix this? WSO2 should test this before release it. It is happening in the SW AS-IS.

I am running it in windows 10 professional (ver 1909) with docker v19.03.13 and docker-compose v1.27.4.

Comment: analytics may use too many connections and this could be due to that. Do you have multiple worker/dashboard running which is pointing to the same MySQL docker?
Also, can you login to the MySQL and check it's maximum connections with the query "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";"

Comment: I have just one worker and one dashboard, like it is in the docker-compose.yml file provided by WSO2. Executing the query I got this result: max_connections 151. It is weird because they are enough connections to be a service without workload. Maybe a misconfiguration that is getting connections in a eager mode?

Comment: Max connection should be 1000 as per the conf(https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/v3.2.0.1/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics/conf/mysql/conf/my.cnf#L4). Did you done any changes to this configs?

Comment: No, i did not change anything in any config so far. All those are defaults configs from WSO2. I will try to change that config in order to fix the problem. Thanks @ruks.